# Classification of Latin Text

Tags: python, classification, text-classification

I am following a tutorial on classification of text - https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/04/a-comprehensive-guide-to-understand-and-implement-text-classification-in-python/.

My text domain is notarial deeds in Latin and the corresponding deed type. This is an extract of my data:

[image]

I only have 150 deeds at present and the text is stripped from any punctuation in a previous step.

When I try the classifiers such as Naive Bayes, after extracting the features, I am getting very low accuracies compared to the example:

```
NB, Count Vectors:  0.02631578947368421
NB, WordLevel TF-IDF:  0.02631578947368421
NB, N-Gram Vectors:  0.02631578947368421
NB, CharLevel Vectors:  0.02631578947368421
```

Any idea why? Is the training set too small?

I have 53 different labels - which I am noticing that there are spelling variations I can correct...but still it is a large number of labels. These are all the labels:

```
  {'Accordium',
 'Apoca',
 'Associacio',
 'Codicillum',
 'Conduccio',
 'Conducio seu locacio',
 'Conductio',
 'Confessio',
 'Confessio permutacionis',
 'Consignacio dotis',
 'Consignatio dotis',
 'Dacio Jnsolutum',
 'Debitum',
 'Debitum Jncabellacio',
 'Divisio',
 'Donacio',
 'Dos',
 'Electio Jurispatronatus',
 'Empcio',
 'Empcio cum gracia',
 'Emptio',
 'Emptio cum gracia',
 'Emptio cum gracia et debitum',
 'Inductio possessionis',
 'Ingabellacio',
 'Jncabellacio',
 'Jncabellacio ovium',
 'Jncabellacio viridarij',
 'Jnduccio possessionjs',
 'Licencia',
 'Locacio',
 'Locacio domus',
 'Locacio persone',
 'Locacio terrarum',
 'Matrimonium',
 'Obligacio',
 'Permutacio',
 'Presentacio Animagij',
 'Presentacio Juris patronatus',
 'Presentacio Jurispatronatus',
 'Presentacio beneficij',
 'Procuracio',
 'Protestacio',
 'Recuperacio',
 'Recusacio JnJunctionis',
 'Remissio',
 'Renunciacio gracie',
 'Responsio protestacionis',
 'Sentencia',
 'Societas',
 'Societas vacce',
 'Testamentum',
 'Transacio'}
```

and this is all the dataframe:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1D6MxfoOLbHzld86Rw1Cso-mpiUpKv7rQ

Comment: How many classes of deeds do you have? And how are your notarial deeds distributed among them?. You can provide a text sample of your data (or all if possible).

Comment: Just uploaded all my data

Comment: Cannot access the data

Comment: Should be ok now

Comment: The provided link is not accessible. Also, some labels seems incorrect: `Emptio` is different than `Empcio` for example? If the number is correct 150 samples for 53 labels seem quite unbalanced. You won't get far from here I think. More samples are required

Comment: I am trying to make my categories more general and correcting such mistakes but can't change much.